# Can't share dataprep flow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm trying to share a Cloud Dataprep flow with some additional users in my business but it won't allow me to share or collaborate with any users in our cloud account:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf3vY.jpg

I thought i'd set permissions up correctly for the users but i'm assuming i've missed something?

Comment: You must enter a valid email account that exists on Google Accounts or in Google Identity Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found out that if the user, to who you try to share a flow, has not signed up at least once in Dataprep before, it will show such error message. Even if the user has all the necessary access rights in the Google Console.
Solution to this then:

1. Setup the users access rights to Dataprep in Google Console / IAM
2. Make sure the users with who you wanna share your flow have registered on Dataprep platform
3. Only then you can share the flows with them

Hope it helped